# How can I get the current scrollY position?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

Consider:

```
const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log(window.scrollY)
  };

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

It doesn’t trigger the scroll event and the log position of scrollY doesn't appear in my browser console...

BTW, I already declare "use client" in my *page.js* file.

Note: I'm using the *App* directory, not the *Pages* directory. I have tried in the *Pages* directory and it worked, but it didn't work in the App directory.

Comment: You should listen to the scroll event only once when the component is mounted. Your example listen to it on every render. Also, I would recommend keeping your handle scroll function inside the same effect since it depends on the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code helps you.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const element = ref.current;
    console.log(element.scrollTop);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => element.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [ref]);
  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ maxHeight: 200, overflow: "scroll" }}>
      {new Array(30).fill(0).map(() => (
        <p>asdf</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```